# How to transform Access data similar to crosstab

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I have data that I want to display similar to a cross-tab query but not quite.  The data I have looks like this with each segment of data on a different row:
[image: Data on each row]

I want the data to be consolidated to be all on one row for each client, like this:
[image: Data all on one row]

I've attempted this with a cross-tab query but I'm not wanting to total any of the fields and there are several data point for each product (Type, Name, PurchaseDate, etc).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very practical presentation of data but it is possible. Need a unique identifier field - autonumber should serve - I called it RID. Consider:

Query 1:

```
SELECT RID, ID, FirstName, LastName, Dept, ProductType AS Data, "PT" AS Cat FROM Table1
UNION SELECT RID, ID, FirstName, LastName, Dept, ProductName, "PN" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT RID, ID, FirstName, LastName, Dept, PurchaseDate, "PD" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT RID, ID, FirstName, LastName, Dept, PurchaseCost, "PC" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT RID, ID, FirstName, LastName, Dept, DeliveryDate, "DD" FROM Table1;
```

Query 2:

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT Query1.ID, Query1.FirstName, Query1.LastName, Query1.Dept
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ID, Query1.FirstName, Query1.LastName, Query1.Dept
PIVOT DCount("*","Query1","ID=" & [ID] & " AND Cat='" & [Cat] & "' AND RID<" & [RID])+1 & [Cat];
```

However, there is a limit of 255 fields so there may be more data than can be handled.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated!